# Use PDF in XCode for an AppIcon (.appiconset collection)

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, icons, springboard

I would like to use a PDF rather than create pixel specific icons. XCode (6 & 6.1) will build device specific pixel images from PDFs during compile for icons but I can't figure out how to get this done for the AppIcon (the Springboard App Icon).

The Icon collection appears to be different from an AppIcon collection (.imageset for icons, .appiconset for the App Icon)

Wondering if anyone has had any luck with this?

Perhaps XCode (v6.1) is not yet capable of this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I can tell: with Xcode 6.1.1, using a PDF is only possible for images, not for the app icons.

Comment: Not in 9.4 as well, just commenting out of hope

Comment: Xcode 12.1, still no support for vector AppIcon. You can add .pdf or .svg assets but not for the AppIcon, why?