# I have Icon with 1x,2x,3x image with navigation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, swift4

I have multi-image I add to bar item image but when I add it shows very big and I can't shrink them I don't know and I have costume back button but when I add it
it shows far from the top left I use this code to add custom back but I add the bar item from storyboard if anyone can help.

[image: this image of icon]

```
let backImg: UIImage = UIImage(named: "back-btn")!
    let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: backImg, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(QuestionViewController.back(sender:)))
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton
```

Comment: Try to use PDF source image instead of using 1x , 2x , 3x .  For ref:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35306051/using-pdfs-for-icon-images-in-xcode-7-2

Answer (score 3):

**Navigation Bar and Toolbar Icon Size**

Use the following sizes for guidance when preparing custom navigation bar and toolbar icons, but adjust as needed to create balance.

[image]

Comment: i use this website to convert icon https://appicon.co/#image-sets
so how to know it's size

Comment: I checked on the website, I could not find a way to specif the size of an icon, try to use a different site.

Comment: but 1x,2x it's the same or what of the sizes you give it 
I'm new about this stuff

Comment: 1x = 24x24, @2x = 48x48, @3x= 72x72 respective sizes.

Answer (score 0):

For navigation set icons in image assets (Assets.xcassets) 1X = 28x28 pixel, 2X = 56x56 pixel and 3X = 84x84 pixel icon size.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/custom-icons/