# Load pdf icon as app icon in Xcode8, 9?

Tags: pdf, xcode8, xcode9, xcode9-beta5

I have a `PDF` app icon and want to drag to `Images.xcassets` to use as app icons. But cannot do that. I can use pdf icon as different icons into my app. But cannot use `PDF` icon for app icons. Please let me know, if `Xcode 8 or 9` is supported it? If not than have any another solutions for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use PDF in XCode for an AppIcon (.appiconset collection)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26689801/use-pdf-in-xcode-for-an-appicon-appiconset-collection)